# Will python multiprocessing suffice for multi-CPU machines?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi, multicore

I am aware that you have to use something like MPI or python libraries like celery, jug, pp, etc, when you want to distribute processes over multiple machines, but is that necessary if you have a single machine with multiple CPU's?

So if I had a machine whose motherboard has two or more CPU's (each with multiple cores) would python's multiprocessing library suffice to fully utilize that machine?

Comment: Yes. In fact, just do `p=multiprocessing.Pool()` and see how many instances you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

"...Due to this, the multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully leverage multiple processors on a given machine..."